# How to convert entire Magento2 Site to Hindi language

Tags: magento2, language-package

how we can convert all the content in the Magento 2 site in to different language like Hindi.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no language pack on the internet, you need to create store with you language and in theme or module create i18n folder with For example: English uk_US.csv file and make translate like "word" : "translation".
For make sentence or word translatable:
in .phtml

```
<?php echo __('sample text') ?>
```

in html

```
<div data-bind="i18n: 'text'">
```

in cms blocks

```
{{trans "text"}}
```

By the way you can you inline-translate in configuration->advanced->developer

Comment: i need to convert entire site and content in to Hindi, not a single word and single sentence.

Comment: @suresh-vagvala You can't click one button and translate entire site :) If you want to translate a content you should make it translatable. magento 2 doesn't work like google translate, every text should be translated by yourself and i showed you how does it works. Easiest way is inline translation in admin panel. By the way language pack triggered for default text that comes up from magento, so for entire translate you need to be a part of it